# NSAttributeDescription, access to the optional properties

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

The Question is: when I use NSAttributeDescription to get access to attribute's properties, I can get access only to basic properties.

```
– attributeType
– setAttributeType:
– attributeValueClassName
– setAttributeValueClassName:
– defaultValue
– setDefaultValue:
```

But How I can get access, for example, to 'max length'  property of string attribute? or else... optional or indexed or transient...

Thank!

Answer (score 3):

I apologize for my previous answer. I read "NSAttributedString" and answered a question you didn't ask, so I deleted it.

First, in answer to your question, NSAttributeDescription is a subclass of [NSPropertyDescription](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSPropertyDescription_Class/NSPropertyDescription.html%23//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSPropertyDescription), which holds the information you're looking for.

**However:** In your comment to my answer, you clarified a bit by saying:

> I want to create sql query, from the
>   entities description. From data model
>   file I can receive parameters of
>   attributes of entity - name, type. Now
>   I can create next query: create table
>   entity_name ( attr1 type1 ); but I
>   want to create next query create table
>   entity_name ( attr1 type1 (max_len));
>   I set 'max_len' param in x-code, when
>   crete model. but I do not understand
>   how i can get this property
>   programmatically, when I parsing a
>   model file.

If you really mean to mess around with SQLite databases created and maintained by Core Data, you need to understand the schema is *not* public and is subject to change without warning. If you make *any* changes, you're likely to corrupt the user's data. Any queries you create may also fail since the schema might suddenly be very different.

So the two caveats are **Make absolutely no changes to a Core Data SQLite document outside Core Data's own machinations.** and **Expect the schema of a Core Data SQLite file to change at any time without warning.**

Answer (score 0):

For those that find this thread looking to set the max length. 
check out :validationPredicate in this document
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataUtilityTutorial/Articles/03_createModel.html